# MySql/php - Tag System

Tags: php, mysql

I'm implementing a Tag system...

Currently i have the table `tags` with `name`, `description`, `createdby` fields.

And the table `images` that have a field `tags`. Inside this field i will put the tags name from the table `tags`, separated by comma.

But, if i want to get all images with tag `Foo` how i do form the query? since the field will contain multiple tags separated by comma.

Comment: I did not tried anything for now, since i do not really know how to from the query.

Comment: I would normalize the data.  Create a table that contains a separate record for each tag for each image.  This would make your query (and life in general) much simpler IMHO.

Comment: @Tom and in terms of database usage and speed it's better to use your method over mine?

Comment: Yes if you have a table with a single tag per record, you could index the tag field and it would be much faster to filter on.  A field with multiple values in it will be much slower to query as you cannot use an index.

Comment: Ok, then i will use your method, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you have thought about normalizing the images table, but that would be the optimal solution here.

Instead of having

[image]

Structure your table this way

[image]

Then you can run this SQL statement to return all images with a certain tag

```
SELECT * FROM images
WHERE tags = 'forest';
```

Or if there is a reason you need to keep your table in the current format, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM images
WHERE tags LIKE '%forest%';
```

The word 'forest' in the above 2 examples is the tag you are searching for

Comment: I would go further and create a `urls` table with `id` and `url` columns, and a `tags` table with `url_id` and `tag` columns.

Comment: Doing so, i need to rewrite all function to get/insert images from the database. So instead i did as Tom said, one table just for record images id and tags id, and join them in a query.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that :

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE tags = 'Foo' OR tags LIKE 'Foo,%' OR tags LIKE '%,Foo' OR tags LIKE '%,Foo,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

store tag ids in `tags` field like this: ',3,17,55,'

when you will exec a query to database, you will be able to use *fast* constructions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE INSTR(tags,',$tag_id,')>'0'
```

instead of using "LIKE '%$tag_id'" which are *slow*

Comment: Storing tags separated by commas aren't a great idea, really.

Comment: i agree, but topic-starter is going to do this way

Comment: True. In addition to your answer, it might be a good idea to explain why this is bad and guide him to the better path.